# How can I make commands appear bold in zsh?

Tags: zsh, colors, prompt

I have set up my bash shell so that any commands I type appear in bold and the commands' output is shown in normal weight:

[image]

I did this by adding `\e[01m` at the end of my `PS1` variable to turn on bold, and using `trap DEBUG` to turn it off:

```
trap 'printf "\e[0m" "$_"' DEBUG
```

That way, the `\e[0m` is printed before each command is executed and I get normal font weight in the output.

How would I go about getting the same effect in `zsh`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The old-fashioned way was to use [`POSTEDIT`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Parameters.html#index-POSTEDIT)

```
 POSTEDIT=$'\e[0m'
```

(and by the way this isn't bash, don't use a DEBUG trap to simulate `preexec`: [zsh is where it's from](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Functions.html#index-preexec)) but since zsh 4.3.11 you can use the command line [syntax highlighting facility](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html#Character-Highlighting). Let your prompt care only about your prompt and set

```
zle_highlight=(default:bold)
```

Answer (score 7):

What you want is [preexec hook function](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Functions.html#index-hook-functions):

```
preexec() { printf "\e[0m"; }
```

Then before each command was executed, `preexec` will be run to reset your font to normal.

So, to get the same prompt you show in your question, add these lines to your `~/.zshrc`:

```
autoload -U colors && colors
PS1="%{$fg_bold[yellow]%}%n@%m %{$fg[blue]%}%~ \$ %{$reset_color%}%{$fg_bold[white]%}"
preexec() { printf "\e[0m"; }
```

Comment: That's the right thing to use instead of a DEBUG trap, but neither is the right way to make the command line bold.